# Is there an automated way to push all my javascript/css/images to s3 everytime I do a website push?

Tags: amazon-s3

So I am in the process of moving all the thumbnails of my major sites to S3 and now I am thinking about how I can consistently put all my CSS/JS/images that power the actual sites to it.  It's easy enough to upload everything the first time but I am trying to think of a way to somehow automate the process everytime I push out to production.

Does anyone have any clever ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [s3sync](http://s3sync.net/wiki) to compare and update the assets just before upload the site files using a bash file to iterate through my files

This works well but when the amount of likes to compare (lets say thousands) gets big this process start being really slow. If you have an small architecture (in term of assets) this would do the trick

to make this better I would recommend [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki) or some other assistant that helps you to deploy...this way you can run at all once..

- upload assets
- deploy your files

In the other hand you could take a look to [cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) (amazon's CDN) and set it up using ORIGIN..this way you dont need to worry about upload the files to s3 since they will be automatically pulled on demand. The down side of this approach is the caching if you need to update a file and keep the same name (AKA expire the object)...you can do this in cloudfront but will need an script to do the task.

Depending in the traffic (and other factors, ofcourse) one or other path will fit the best.